# Azure: DrainMode stopping ServiceBus listeners spams TaskCanceledException

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

We're running several ServiceBus listeners in Azure Functions on the Azure platform. We are using consumption plan, meaning resources on Azure are assigned/unassigned as needed. When Azure unassigns resources, it enables DrainMode. This causes all the ServiceBus batch listeners to print a lengthy error.

[image: Screenshot of console]
The image shows only 2 of the errors but there are many more. This is flooding our AppInsights unnecessarily.

I tried many things to prevent printing the error; none of which worked.

- Surround all ServiceBus functions in try/catch;
- Handling CancellationToken in the ServiceBus functions as described in the first answer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/770912/why-do-i-see-drainmode-mode-enabled-in-the-logs-an) and in Microsoft docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library?tabs=v4%2Ccmd#cancellation-tokens).

The errors are still being printed. Does anyone know how i can prevent them from showing up that doesn't involve changing log levels?

```
[Error]   sbt-alarms/Subscriptions/sbs-alarms-log-41ea7d07-9a99-4ffe-9de9-e91713d7d6d7: ReceiveBatchAsync Exception: System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.

   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)

   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.ReceivingAmqpLink.EndReceiveMessages(IAsyncResult result, IEnumerable`1& messages)

   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.ReceivingAmqpLink.<>c.<ReceiveMessagesAsync>b__27_1(IAsyncResult r)

   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)

--- End of stack trace from previous location ---

   at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Amqp.AmqpReceiver.ReceiveMessagesAsyncInternal(Int32 maxMessages, Nullable`1 maxWaitTime, TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Amqp.AmqpReceiver.<>c.<<ReceiveMessagesAsync>b__41_0>d.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location ---

   at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusRetryPolicy.RunOperation[T1,TResult](Func`4 operation, T1 t1, TransportConnectionScope scope, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean logRetriesAsVerbose)

   at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusRetryPolicy.RunOperation[T1,TResult](Func`4 operation, T1 t1, TransportConnectionScope scope, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean logRetriesAsVerbose)

   at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Amqp.AmqpReceiver.ReceiveMessagesAsync(Int32 maxMessages, Nullable`1 maxWaitTime, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusReceiver.ReceiveMessagesAsync(Int32 maxMessages, Nullable`1 maxWaitTime, Boolean isProcessor, CancellationToken cancellationToken).
```

Thanks!

Comment: What version of the `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus` package are you using?   Behavior for drain mode cancellation was changed with v5.12.0 back in August to prevent this pattern.

Comment: @JesseSquire upgrading the package did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These errors are printed in above scenario when the package `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus` is used at an outdated version.

Upgrade the package to `v5.12.0` and handle batch message cancellation through `IDrainModeManager` using `IsDrainModeEnabled`.

Inject `IDrainModeManager` in the constructor of the class. And then in the batch function:

```
foreach (var message in messages)
{
    if (_drainModeManager.IsDrainModeEnabled)
    {
        // Handle cancellation
        break;
    }
    // Handle message normally
}
```

**Note**: In this case `AutoCompleteMessages` should be set to `false` and messages should be completed manually unless canceled.